# Camera.lock, unlock() managed automatically for you since Android 4.0?

Tags: android, android-camera

I just started android development and wrote a simple camera app using this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

there i read: "Note: Starting with Android 4.0 (API level 14), the Camera.lock() and Camera.unlock() calls are managed for you automatically."

but what does this mean? my camera app supports Android 16 (4.1.2) and 17 (4.2.2) but if i discard the lock and unlock calls i get error from mediarecorder (-19). so how to let handle android it? or what does this mean "managed automatically"?

Comment: Good question. I face same issue and at the end left lock/unlock calls, cause i couldn't make it work without this error. It can however be related with my min SDK that was API 15 (4.0.3), despite the testing (and getting error -19) on 4.2.2..

Answer (score 1):

As android [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#lock()) `lock()` is called automatically for you in `MediaRecorder.start()`.
I think that you couldn't remove the unlock() call because when the `start()` method call the `lock()` method on your camera, which is locked by default, it find the camera locket and so it rise a `RuntimeException`.

> Since API level 14, camera is automatically locked for applications in
>   start(). Applications can use the camera (ex: zoom) after recording
>   starts. There is no need to call this after recording starts or stops.